# Do we need to consider the cases when both $x$ and $y$ are not irrational?

Tags: solution-verification

Suppose there is no rational points on $x^2 + y^2 = c$ where $c $ is a constant. If we plug in $x=0$, then there is no rational solution for $y^2=c$. Thus, $y=\sqrt{c}$ is irrational and we show that $\sqrt{c}$ is irrational.

This is the proof I saw in [$x^2 + y^2 - 3 = 0 \implies 3^{1/2}$ is irrational.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022154/x2-y2-3-0-implies-31-2-is-irrational).

Do we need to consider the case when both $x$ and $y$ are irrational? If not, why? Is it possible for both not be rational but $\sqrt{c}$ is rational? Thanks.

Comment: By assumption $x^2+y^2=c$ has no rational solutions, this is defined to mean that there are no $x,y$ both rational that solve this equation. In other words if $(x,y)$ is a solution of this equation then at least one of $x,y$ is irrational. Since you pick $x=0$ which is rational then $y$ must be irrational.

Comment: There’s no need to consider cases other than $(x, y) = (0, \sqrt{3})$; even cases where $x$ is rational and non-zero are irrelevant. If $\sqrt{3}$ were rational, this would be a rational point on $x^2 + y^2 = 3$, but (due to some other proof elsewhere), no rational points exist. By contradiction, $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

Comment: $x=y=\sqrt{2}, c=2$.