# Help with understanding of proof of no rational points on $x^2+y^2=3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

In Julian Havil's *The Irrationals*, he at one point in Chapter 2 supposedly states a proof that there are no points with rational coordinates on the curve $x^2+y^2=3$. He begins:

"Assume that a rational point $(p/q, r/s)$ lies on the circle and so $p^2/q^2+r^2/s^2 = 3$, resulting in $p^2s^2+q^2r^2=3q^2s^2$ and so $(ps)^2+(qr)^2 = 3(qs)^2$ and therefore the existence of positive integers so that $a^2+b^2=3c^2$. **Since the sum of two even numbers and the sum of two odd numbers are each even, it must be that one of $a^2$ and $b^2$ is even and the other odd;** so..."

and continues. I understand every step other than this - why does the fact that one of $a^2$ and $b^2$ must be even and the other odd from the simple fact about the sums of odd and even numbers?

Comment: I don't understand the argument.  Is that all?   Can you post the whole proof?

Comment: Well, I expect you are to assume that the triple $(a,b,c)$ is minimal.  If $a,b$ are both odd then $a^2+b^2\equiv 2 \pmod 4$ but $3c^2$ can't be $2\pmod 4$.  If $a,b$ are both even then $c$ is even so $\left(\frac a2,\frac b2,\frac c2\right)$ is a smaller triple.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319553/show-that-the-curve-x2y2-3-0-has-no-rational-points) by the way, is a good discussion of the problem.

Comment: Thanks @lulu! That's very helpful. For the record, I find it irritating that this was marked as a duplicate - it's a classic annoying thing for you to ask why a specific proof method works/fails and then the reply to be, "Don't worry about that! *Here*'s a better proof method...", rather than actually addressing your question.

Comment: Yes...it was clear to me that you were asking about a specific detail in a given proof, not about the problem in general.  Did I explain that detail clearly enough?

Comment: You very much did so! Thanks. It's always amusing to me how even in a semi-popular mathematics book, the proofs can still have implicit steps which I can't immediately follow.

Comment: @IskyMathews Yo you on camp yet or nah Isky