# For what integer values of $k$ does $a^{2}+b^{2}=kc^{2}$ have positive integer solutions?

Tags: diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

The obvious case of $k=1$ clearly has solutions, for example, $(3,4,5)$ and $(5,12,13)$, among others. Trivially, it has infinitely many solutions by multiplying through by any number. It has infinitely many solutions aside from those that can be parametrized by $(2nm,n^{2}-m^{2},n^{2}+m^{2})$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$. This is a well-known result.

The case of $k=2$ also has infinitely many solutions, among them $(1,7,5)$. As in the previous example I can simply multiply through by any number and get another valid triple. At some point just after Christmas I had worked out a parametrization (using the method of finding a rational point on the corresponding circle), but I cannot recall it off the top of my head. It was not much more complicated than for the case of $k=1$, however, and I sincerely doubt that I was the first one to have found it.

The case of $k=3$ is one for which I have been unable to find any solutions, but I cannot think of a proof that it has no solutions. I cannot find any rational points on the circle $x^{2}+y^{2}=3$, but that does not mean that those points do not exist.

The case of $k=4$ has solutions as well. Given $a^{2}+b^{2}=4c^{2}$, merely allow $d=2c$ and we return to the case of $k=1$ with the question of finding triples that satisfy $a^{2}+b^{2}=d^{2}$. This shows that the original question that I posed is equivalent to merely asking which squarefree integers $k$ have solutions.

I have similarly found solutions in the case of $k=5$, for example, $(11,2,5)$. Try as I might, I have found nothing for the cases of $k=6$ or $k=7$. The cases of $k=8$ and $k=9$ have solutions by a similar argument as the previous paragraph.

Initially, my guess was that there no solutions iff $k\cong3\mod4$ given my inability to find solutions in the $k=3$ and $k=7$ cases, until I decided to look at the $k=6$ case as well and found that I was similarly stumped. I feel like there's something else obvious that I'm overlooking, but whether it's solutions for the cases I can't find a solution for or some other connection between these numbers, I don't have a clue.

My apologies if this has been asked before, I couldn't find anything when I did a google search.

Comment: For $k = 3$, this may be of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319553/show-that-the-curve-x2y2-3-0-has-no-rational-points

Comment: If it helps in looking for information on it, the equation you have is the projective form of the generalized Pell equation $x^2 - dy^2 = k$ with $d = -1$. At the very least, there are no solutions for $k\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ because $3$ is not the sum of two squares in $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses! The previous question here on the case of $k=3$ does indeed do wonders to confirm my suspicions that I was unable to find any solutions because they do not exist. I do not know much about the generalized Pell equation, as I am still an undergraduate. The sum of two squares theorem is about which numbers are the sums of squares of two integers (if I'm thinking of the right one), but there are integers that are the sums of squares of two non-integer rationals - for instance, $5=2.2^{2}+0.4^{2}$, and such points would also lead to solutions.

Comment: @SquarefreeEquation Yes, it leads to the solution
$$2^2+11^2=5^3=5\cdot 5^2,$$
for $k=5$ (or $k=125$). You are only asking about integral solutions, right?

Comment: I think that finding rational solutions should be the same as finding integral solutions, just multiply by all the denominators.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767109/x2y2-2z2-positive-integer-solutions/1767719#1767719

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) tells you that for a given integer $k$, the equation
$$a^2+b^2=kc^2,$$
has a solution in positive integers if and only if $k$ does not have a prime factor $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$ with odd multiplicity. That is, if $k=\prod p^{v_p}$ is the prime factorization of $k$, then there exist solutions if an only if $v_p\equiv0\pmod{2}$ whenever $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

For $a^2+b^2=kc^2$ to have integers solutions, $k$ can be the square of any  prime factor of a composite hypotenuse of a Pythagorean triple. Among the  values [here](https://oeis.org/A009003) $\quad k\in\{4, 9, 16, 25,\cdots \}\quad $ suggests that $k$ can be any prime squared.

For example
$$ 12^2+16^2=20^2=4^2\cdot 5^2
\implies a=12,\space b=16,\space k=16,\space c=5$$
We find that $\quad p\equiv 3\mod 4\quad $ is allowed. I'm not sure what the earlier answer meant.

$$21^2+28^2=35^2=7^2\cdot 5^2
\implies a=21,\space  b=28,\space  k=49,\space c=5 $$

If we examine this further, it appears that $k$ can be any integer squared: $\quad k=j^2,\space  j\in\mathbb{N}\quad$ because the extended Pythagorean Theorem states $(\space jA^2+(\space jB)^2=(\space jC^2)\quad$ and we have seen the $\space 7\times(3,4,5)\space $ combination  as being perfectly valid above.

Comment: If $k$ is a perfect square, the problem then reduces again to Pythagorean triples. Write $k=r^2$ to get the equation $a^2+b^2=(rc)^2$.